# Using vh and wh as responsive units is giving my img a margin, on mobile

Tags: html, css, media-queries, responsive, viewport-units

I fixed one responsive design problem and introduced another. I've made a cool svg and in it I've included some text. I know, I know – I should've added text via HTML/CSS. But my website is due today and I've spent too much time on graphics, so I can't afford to turn the SVG into a responsive div.

At first, using max-width 100% would make the vector text far too large on a computer monitor and far too tiny on mobile. I designed the vector for mobile-first, so It is long and vertical (2300px with 3000px)

I managed to fix that dilemma by including vh and wh as units.

But now, the image is moved down when it goes to mobile-view. Mobile-view introduces empty white space between the element above and the image.

No margins, no paddings on image div. The elements above don't have any. The body also doesn't have any.

Any clue as to what could be introducing this?

Thank you so much in advance!

HTML

```
<div class="vector">
        <img class="vector-img" src="dark.svg">
   </div>
```

CSS

```
    width: 95wh;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
```

Comment: Please upload your code to the sandbox or codepen or StackOverflow code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have set two classes, "vector" and "vector-img", and that might cause the problem. Please provide more code if possible. You also have typo in your css, change width: 95**wh**; to width: 95**vh**;

Answer (score 0):

Note that on at least some mobiles eg iOS vh is not necessarily the viewport height, it is a fixed height so that when the user scrolls and some of the chrome at the top of the browser window disappears there isn’t a sudden jump for the user.

This makes it hard not to get gaps, or some info cut off at the bottom of the window.

If you could put a working example up in your answer we would be able to see more clearly whether this is causing your problem or not.

Note: you are setting the width to a wh unit. I suspect you mean vw, but that is probably not causing the problem you describe.